# mysql REPLACE INTO table with hundreds of columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with hundreds of columns. The table structure is out of my control (controlled by a third party). The table also has horrendous field names with spaces, single quotes, etc. and so do the table values. The table is updated once per hour via cron. The cron job truncates and rebuilds the table each time. I also keep an archive table of that table, that I use a REPLACE INTO statement to update or insert as required.

My challenge - I prefer not to have to explicitly define all 350 field names and values, and do so again in my REPLACE INTO statement as this will take a very long time and will require maintenance if the table changes. I would much rather use arrays. Here is what is not working but hopefully gives an idea of the goal (I realize this is deprecated MySQL but it is what it is for a variety of reasons):

```
$listings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM current.table");

while ($listing = mysql_fetch_assoc($listings)){

    //prepare variables

    $fields = array_keys($listing);
    $fields = implode('`, `', $fields);
    $fields = "`$fields`";

    $values = array_values($listing);
    $values = implode("`, `", $values);
    $values = "`$values`";

    mysql_query('REPLACE INTO archive.table ($fields) VALUES ($values)');

}
```

Comment: Define 'not working'. Have you identified at what stage a problem is occurring?

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` on the queries. What you posted seems legit code, however values needs to be quoted `'` and escaped for possible injection, not ticked `\``. While using double quotes `"` for the second query's encapsulation. `mysql_query("REPLACE INTO archive.table ($fields) VALUES ($values)");`

Comment: Why not use `DROP TABLE archive.table; CREATE TABLE archive.table LIKE current.table; INSERT INTO archive.table SELECT * FROM current.table`?

Comment: Or even `drop table archive.table; create table archive.table as select * from current.table`. But the real question is of course: What happened to your data model that resulted in a table with 350 columns?!

Comment: Erroneous single quotes on mysql_query statement was the culprit. I also did mysql_real_escape_string on $values and used single quotes instead of ticks. Worked like a charm!
while ($listing = mysql_fetch_assoc($listings)){
 $fields = array_keys($listing);
 $fields = implode('`, `', $fields);
 $fields = "`$fields`";
 $values = array_values($listing);
 $values = implode("`, `", $values);
 $values = mysql_real_escape_string($values);
 $values = str_replace("`","'",$values);
 $values = "'$values'";
 mysql_query("REPLACE INTO archive.table ($fields) VALUES ($values)");  
}

Comment: @Tavish You're welcome, glad to have been of help and welcome to Stack.

Comment: And don't use mysql_query anymore. That one is deprecated (and removed in PHP 7.0). Use mysqli_query or PDO. `It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7`.

Comment: @Rik They don't have a choice to use the mysql_ API, if you read the question again ;-) as per OP: *"(I realize this is deprecated MySQL but it is what it is for a variety of reasons)"*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah, `controlled by a third party`. Ok, maybe shooting a message to that third party might be advisable in that case. But you're correct. I missed that line stating OP knew about it.

Comment: @Rik I was thinking the same thing earlier also. One has to wonder why that is, maybe a server that can't be upgraded for many unknown reasons... sometimes it takes a lot of time to reconfigure one and if there isn't much demand for it, then they just put it on the backburner for a while. I was victim of that once, when they finally decided to do it after a 4 year roar. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki, no rep should come from this since it did solve the OP's question (as per suggested in comments).

> *"Aha! Erroneous single quotes on the mysql_query statement was the culprit. I also did mysql_real_escape_string on $values and used single quotes instead of ticks. Worked like a charm. Thank you! Final answer: – Tavish"*

Use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) on the queries. What you posted seems legit code, however values needs to be quoted `'` and [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for possible injection, not ticked. 
While using double quotes `"` for the second query's encapsulation.

```
mysql_query("REPLACE INTO archive.table ($fields) VALUES ($values)");
```

As well as other suggestions given.

OP's final code (taken from comments):

```
while ($listing = mysql_fetch_assoc($listings)){ 
    $fields = array_keys($listing); 
    $fields = implode(', ', $fields); 
    $fields = "$fields"; 
    $values = array_values($listing); 
    $values = implode(", ", $values); 
    $values = mysql_real_escape_string($values); 
    $values = str_replace("`","'",$values); 
    $values = "'$values'"; 
    mysql_query("REPLACE INTO archive.table ($fields) VALUES ($values)"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! while ($listing = mysql_fetch_assoc($listings)){ $fields = array_keys($listing); $fields = implode(', ', $fields); $fields = "$fields"; $values = array_values($listing); $values = implode(", ", $values); $values = mysql_real_escape_string($values); $values = str_replace("`","'",$values); $values = "'$values'"; mysql_query("REPLACE INTO archive.table ($fields) VALUES ($values)"); }

Comment: @Tavish You're most welcome. I did pull your code from the comments under your question, *cheers*